# Using LibVLC in Android application - Unresolved methods

Tags: android, libvlc

I want to use LibVLC in my Android application.

I added below line to gradle dependencies to use precompiled LibVLC library.

> compile 'de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:3.0.0'

When I use below code i get this error.

> Cannot resolve method 'getInstance()'

My initialization code is

```
mLibVLC = LibVLC.getInstance();
```

My imports are

```
import org.videolan.libvlc.EventHandler;
import org.videolan.libvlc.IVideoPlayer;
import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaList;
```

and my class definition is

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements IVideoPlayer
```

Should i add another definitions to my project to solve this problem?

Comment: It imports but could not find?

Comment: Aynen böyle oluyor... Exactly.. I can import them without problem, but can not find the methods.

Comment: May I know what's the reason you have chosen libvlc. Unlike iOS, Android has a good view called VideoView.

Comment: I want to use password capability to protect stream form public view. I dont know that if the VideoView has this feature. After unsuccessfull implementation of LibVLC class, I switch to calling an intent which opens a video activity. So i can use vlan application to view video. Can i open password protected html stream with VideoView class?

Comment: You mean an rtsp streaming with password protection? If so, sure you can stream it using videoview.

Comment: The streaming bash line is
`cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:width=576:height=432:fps=30 --v4l2-vflip 1 --v4l2-hflip 1  --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{preset=fast,lookahead=120,keyint=120}}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8090}"`

i think it is not a rtsp stream, however i m not sure. is there and sample to view protected stream with videoview to try?